# Join в Laravel Eloquent по массиву ID

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

Добрый день. 
Имеется две таблицы, geo_profiles:

> ```
> id
> name
> country_code
> ```

Вторая, banners:

> ```
> id
> name
> ...
> geo_profile_id  // <-- тип поля TEXT информация хранится в виде массива.
> ```

В модели App/Models/Banner.php у меня указано, что поле geo_profile_id - массив, что бы хранить несколько значений.

```
protected $casts = [
        'geo_profile'  => 'array',
    ];
```

При получении данных из модели я ожидаемо получаю массив айдишников:

```
dd(Banner::get());

результат:
"geo_profile" => "["4","6"]"
```

Можно ли в этом случае сделать join склейку с первой таблицей по массиву id?

Comment: Лучше бы хранили эти значения связей в отдельной таблице и не было бы проблем с выводом связующих данных и целостность не была бы нарушена за счёт внешних ключей.

Comment: Можно прописать в модели Banner метод, который возвращал бы коллекцию geo_profiles вручную, вроде `public function geo_profiles() { return GeoProfile::whereIn('id', $this->geo_profile)->get(); } `